# Failed when deploying in Render without a specific error message

Tags: node.js, deployment, render

I am trying to host my server using Render but it always failed and the render cant even show up a specific error message my structured of my directory seems well and organized. Please help me.
[PICTURE OF MY BUILDING LOGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRUHw.png)

I already set the NODE_VERSION through .env and retried again and again but still no luck:(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.